# Maintain state of toggle switch flutter drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a drawer in my app and I want to maintain the state of toggle switch in it.
How can i do this ?
This is the code

```
SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: SizedBox(
                              height: 25,
                              width: 25,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/sideMenu/Bell.png',
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Transform.translate(
                                offset: const Offset(-14, 0),
                                child: const Text('Notifications',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white))),
                            trailing: SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                                width: 40,
                                child: Transform.scale(
                                  scale: 1.3,
                                  child: Switch.adaptive(
                                      value: value,
                                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                                      activeTrackColor: const Color.fromARGB(
                                          255, 35, 187, 40),
                                      onChanged: (value) =>
                                          setState(() => this.value = value)),
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Anything I can do to make this maintain its state?

This is how it works now  :

[image]

Comment: Can you include your build method?

Comment: use value notifier to maintain the state and valuenotifier builder to listen the changes without any state management solutuons

Comment: @AliHassan He is already using  `StatefulWidget`, no need to use valueNotifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shared preferences and save the state on press

```dart
onChanged: (val)async{
  setState((){value = val});
  SharedPreferences prefs= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool("notificationStatus", val);
}
```

Then in initstate you can set the value

```
bool value = true;
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
 fetchNotificationStatus();
}
fetchNotificationStatus() async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  value = prefs.getBool("notificationStatus")??true;
 setState((){});
}
```

Comment: I think it is about maintaining the state rather than saving user setting

Comment: Yes this did exactly what I wanted. thankyou

Comment: Yeah @YeasinSheikh. But since he wrote it in a class each time the page opened it would reset to true. So unless he saves it or keeps it globally it wont work i think. Thats why suggested to save in shared preferences.